# Do marketplace creators get money or minecoins?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was just wondering, if someone applies to be a marketplace creator, do they get money or minecoins?

Comment: a share of money earned i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minecraft map creators are paid in money.  Minecoins are simply a universal ingame currency.